# Linking a .chm or URL to the title bar help button for a ProWindow

Tags: arcgis-pro-sdk

I noticed that the ProWindow exposes a "ShowHelpButton" property which shows a "?" on the title bar, but a click navigates to the ArcGIS Pro help website. Both the ArcGIS Pro SDK repository and the API reference have no guidance on the property's use (the API doesn't even show the property as a [member](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/sdk/api-reference/#topic15056.html)). Is there anyway to point the help button to custom help content (e.g., a .chm file or a different URL)?

Comment: I'm working with a Managed Configuration if that makes a difference